# Mongoose C++ Http server get only MG_OPEN_FILE event

Tags: c++, mongoose-web-server

I have this server using mongoose, which take some request, parse the informations, do an action and return the result.

For exemple, I can query it this way server:port/action?arg1=test&arg2=...

My problem is that any time I query the server I get only "MG_OPEN_FILE" events. And for each request I get 3 of them.

I read that it may be normal to have some in http queries but the problem here is that I don't have any "MG_NEW_REQUEST" events.

Basically, whenever I start the server, the first connection (and all of them after) always returns the following events: 
MG_OPEN_FILE

MG_OPEN_FILE

MG_OPEN_FILE

MG_REQUEST_COMPLETE

I call my server this way :

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  struct mg_context *ctx;
  const char *options[] = {"listening_ports", "8080", "num_threads","10",  NULL};
  ctx = mg_start(&callback, NULL, options);
  while(1){  
      getchar(); // Wait until user hits "enter"
  }
  mg_stop(ctx);
  return 0;
}
```

And the callback function starts with :

```
static void *callback(enum mg_event event, struct mg_connection *conn)
{

const struct mg_request_info *request_info = mg_get_request_info(conn);
if (event == MG_NEW_REQUEST)
{
```

But it is always a "MG_OPEN_FILE" event and I have no clue of the reason :(
So if anyone has any idea on the reason of this, I would be extremely thankful !

Comment: That's an older version of mongoose. There are now separate callback functions for each callback event.

Answer (score 1):

When you're getting `MG_OPEN_FILE`, check `(char *) mg_get_request_info(conn)->ev_data`
It contains file name mongoose wants to open.
If you have that file in memory, return it's data and size.
If you don't, return `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Is your callback returning that you procssed the event?  I only return "yes" if I process the event.